# How to get in C++ a function pointer to a member function with bound variables?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I would like to call a function `g` (from a 3rd party library) that takes as input a pointer to a function `f`. This function pointer is such that `f` itself takes some arguments.

As my function `f` depends on data and I cannot pass (a reference to) this data as a parameter to the function `f` because I need to implement `f` using the signature that is used in the function pointer, I would like to do one of two things:

- implement `f` as a (non-static) member function of a class
- implement a helper function `fHelper` that takes additional arguments and then construct a function pointer (but not a function object) that has the signature of the function pointer used in `g` and calls `fHelper` with the additional arguments bound to specific values.

A third solution that is neither thread-safe nor acceptable from the perpective of design would be to use a global variable.

I have looked at `boost:bind` and `std::mem_fun` but do not understand if these concepts work in this setting. I would very much appreciate an instructive answer and possibly some background on how this case is usually handled.

Comment: A well designed interface will either be implemented as a template which would allow a functor object instead of a pointer to a function, or it includes an unused value that a static function can cast back to an object pointer. If you don't have either of those you're out of luck.

Comment: Please make your question title _describe the question_, instead of just listing some features of C++.

Comment: I won't put this in the answers cuz I havn't played with them yet, but maybe try lamda functions in C++11? Casting to a function pointer is going to be a pain no matter what.

Comment: Thanks, Mark! I had the suspicion that the last parameter of type `void*` should be used for this purpose, but I was not aware that this is common practice. Considering the fact that this pattern is not obvious and that we cannot inline the function, I see function objects as a strong advantage of C++ over C.

Comment: I think that only way to solve this is to create function during runtime that holds pointer to object with your operator(). http://fscked.org/projects/minihax/c-functor-c-function-pointer-conversion . This is achieved by coping code on heap. Avoid this

Comment: @Bjoern: It is **very** common for C callback interfaces to have such a `void*` parameter. The C++ convention with such interfaces is to wrap all arguments in a class, and make the callback itself a simple `static` method of that class.